# combining knockout js with truffle app.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, solidity, truffle

I am learning on how to create a voting app with truffle and rendering on the screen everything goes well. So now I don't want to use vanilla js but want to add a framework to it, called `knockout.js`

I tried it in everyway but for some reason the knockout js is not working inside the app.js file given by truffle framework.

Here is the piece of code that works but it looks like the observables don't really work at all.

```
function AppViewModel() { // Loading the appviewmodel
var self = this;
  App = {
    web3Provider: null,
    contracts: {},
    account: '0x0',

    init: function() {
      return App.initWeb3();
    },

    initWeb3: function() {
      // TODO: refactor conditional
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
        App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
        App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
        web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
      }
      return App.initContract();
    },

    initContract: function() {
      $.getJSON("Election.json", function(election) {
        // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
        App.contracts.Election = TruffleContract(election);
        // Connect provider to interact with contract
        App.contracts.Election.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
        return App.render();
      });
    },

    render: function() {
      var electionInstance;
      var loader = $("#loader");
      var content = $("#content");
      var name = ko.observable('masnad'); //added the observable!

      loader.show();
      content.hide();

      // Load account data
      web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
        if (err === null) {
          App.account = account;
          $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
        }
      });

      // Load contract data
      App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        electionInstance = instance;
        return electionInstance.candidatesCount();
      }).then(function(candidatesCount) {
        var candidatesResults = $("#candidatesResults");
        candidatesResults.empty();

        for (var i = 1; i <= candidatesCount; i++) {
          electionInstance.candidates(i).then(function(candidate) {
            console.log(candidate);
            var id = candidate[0];
            var name = candidate[1];
            var voteCount = candidate[2];

            // Render candidate Result
            var candidateTemplate = "<tr><th>" + id + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + voteCount + "</td></tr>"
            candidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate);
          });
        }

        loader.hide();
        content.show();
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.warn(error);
      });
    }
  };
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById('vote_app'));
    App.init();
});
```

I have attached comments on the above code where the knockout js observables are used but unfortunetly in the HTML file they don't exist.

Here is the piece of code on the HTML file that should work..

```
<h1 class="text-center"><span data-bind="text:name"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout is not able to find the observable because you initialized it as a local variable, i.e., as `var name = ...`

Instead, you need to make it a property of the viewModel instance using the `this` operator, because that's how you expose it to the HTML.

Try replacing that line with

```
self.name = ko.observable('masnad');
```

Comment: P.S. it would be better in the future to mention the error(s) you get as well.

Comment: Hi Ray, yea sorry for that , the piece of code I added was few mins older since I changed var name to self.name already...

The problem is still the same actually, that I can't see it appear on the html page.

Comment: nopes, very confusing, but I guess I gave up already, using pure js